# Pushing to the repository created by Gitlab fails with error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab

An error occurred when pushing to the repository created by GitLab,
I wanted to give advice.

Push operation itself, from Windows 10 PC,
I did it using TortoiseGit.

[Error message displayed]

> > git.exe push --progress "origin" master: master
> >
> > Enumerating objects: 8, done. Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
> >     Delta compression using up to 8 threads. Compressing objects: 100%
> >     (3/3), done. Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 532 bytes | 532.00 KiB / s,
> >     done. Total 6 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0) remote:
> >     /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:153:in
> >     parse_who ': undefined method start_with?' for nil: NilClass
> >     (NoMethodError) remote: from
> >     /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb: 31: in
> >     check_access' remote: from
> >     /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_access.rb:27:in
> >     block in exec ' remote: from
> >     /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_metrics.rb: 50:
> >     in measure ' remote: from
> >     /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_access.rb:26: in
> >     exec ' remote: from hooks / pre-receive: 30: in ` ' To ssh: //
> >     :  / ~ /  /test_system.git
> >     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
> >     error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh: // git @ :  / ~ /  /test_system.git'
>
> git did not end normally (exit code 1) (1125 ms @ 2018/10/21 16: 47:
>   10)

I would be pleased if you give me advice.
Thank you.

Additional Information:

System information
System:
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.4.4p296
Gem Version:    2.7.6
Bundler Version:1.16.2
Rake Version:   12.3.1
Redis Version:  3.2.11
Git Version:    2.18.1
Sidekiq Version:5.1.3
Go Version:     unknown

GitLab information
Version:        11.3.5
Revision:       c74e8d9
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     postgresql
URL:
HTTP Clone URL: 
SSH Clone URL:
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        8.3.3
Repository storage paths:
- default:      /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
Hooks:          /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks
Git:            /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it comes from TortoiseGit in itself. But more likely that the default setting of Gitlab is to protect the `master` branch. See [Gitlab protected branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html)

In your case, you can see the main error is :

> "! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs"

It means that your **remote** (here, your Gitlab server) is **rejecting the push** for the reason `"pre-receive hook declined"`.

To change that, go to : `Project > Settings > Repository > Protected branches`

Here you can remove or add protected branches, and you can edit push settings for protected branches.
[image: Gitlab protected branches settings]